# Java - Best Way to Convert Characters in a String (Arrays, if-then, hash-map)?

Tags: java, arrays, string

**Title:** (Java Beginner) - In Java, what would be the recommended way to replace a series of characters within strings?

**Issue/Example:** I would like certain characters within a group of strings to be replaced by other characters. (e.g. all 'a's will be replaced by 'aa' and all 'あ' characters will be replaced by 'a')

*Data example:*
Tammy,Tあmmy,John Jones KO'd Machida,The Drall,あい

*Changed to:*
Taammy,Tammy,John Johes KO'd Mあchida,The Draall,aい

I'm doing this using an if-then statement, but this isn't scalable as there are potentially hundreds of if-thens to perform. I'm currently just worried about the logic and haven't thought of how to handle the data source files yet, which will be either csv file or a flatfile format.

*Question*: Should I be looking at arrays? hashmaps? collections?

The current code is similar to the below, but I understand that it is inefficient. I would like to know how I might be able to do this more efficiently.

```
public static String formatString(String s) 
{

        //Declare Variables
        String strInput = s;
        String strChanged = "";

        //Iterate through length of string
        for (int i = 0; i < strInput.length(); i++)
        {
          if (strInput.charAt(i)=='あ')
          {
              strChanged = strChanged + "a";    
          }
          else if (strInput.charAt(i)=='a')
          {
              strChanged = strChanged + "aa";
          }
          else if (strInput.charAt(i)=='c')
          {
              strChanged = strChanged + "k";
          }
          else
          {
              strChanged = strChanged + strInput.charAt(i);
          }
        }
        System.out.println(strChanged);
}
```

Caveats:
-up to 200 different characters which need to be changed
-looping through potentially thousands of rows of data

Comment: I would use a regular expression with a lookup table. The regular expression (matching only those characters that should be changed) can be generated off the lookup data, which is itself created as a simple data structure - the code itself does *not* contain the data.

Comment: Is the input to be replaced always a single character? Are you sure that those "characters" aren't decomposed? Are you running in a constrained environment where a largish lookup table would be infeasible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using a `HashMap` to reduce the number of if statements

```
String input = "Tammy,Tあmmy,John Jones KO'd Machida,The Drall,あい";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Map<Character, CharSequence> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('あ', "a");
map.put('a', "aa");
map.put('c', "k");

for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (map.containsKey(c)) {
        builder.append(map.get(c));
    } else {
        builder.append(c);
    }
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: This is a correct answer.  I will write an alternative using StringBuffer.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas Why an alternative with `StringBuffer`? There is absolutely no need for a `StringBuffer` here...

Comment: Why not? Isn't it possible to do it with it?

Comment: It's possible to do with a `StringBuffer`, but in this case, I absolutely fail to see the need for synchronization that `StringBuffer` brings. It's inside a single method and the builder/buffer isn't shared. You'll lose in performance. See [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Comment: @yate, thank you very much for your solution. This has helped a lot. BTW, I know this might be a sub-topic, but wondering if there's anywhere I can look to see performance impact on Hasmaps vs. If-then iterations vs. replace statements? Just curious

Comment: @yate thank you for your answer. The code works great for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)? String.replace() and friends ought to do what you want in one or two passes.

Answer (score 0):

String.replace is very inefficient. To improve performance, see Peter Lawrey's answer to [Is String.replace implementation really efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517990/is-string-replace-implementation-really-efficient)

Answer (score -1):

There are several solutions:

A different way of using your approach might be to use a `switch` statement.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strInput.length(); i++)
    {
      cur = strInput.charAt(i)
      switch (cur){
          case 'あ': ... 
              break;
          case 'a': ...   
              break;
          case 'c': ...    
              break;
          ...
    }
    System.out.println(strChanged);
```

Switch statements are often a good alternative to long if/else trains. Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

A more readable solution would be to use the `String.replaceAll()` method for each case. The drawback to this is the runtime would be slower. A thousand lines is small enough to not make a significant difference, but it is important to keep these limitations in mind. In addition, if you replace 'あ' with 'a' then 'a' with 'aa', you might accidentally get the wrong results. Write tests!